# macOS emacs in the terminal (no GUI)

Tags: ui, emacs

Since the update to macOS Catalina, I installed Emacs separately using `brew cask install emacs`. Now when I type `emacs` in Terminal, Emacs is opened in a separate window with a GUI (the Emacs.app?). How do I get back to just a plain old Emacs in the terminal with no GUI?

Comment: How did you install Emacs?

Comment: brew cask install emacs

Comment: Does running `emacs -nw` help?

Comment: Sure does. I added `alias emacs = 'emacs -nw'` to my .bash_profile and now I have the old behavior. Thank you! Incidentally, `man emacs` does not have an entry.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to run

```
emacs -nw
```

(„no window“) to prevent it from opening a new window.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for macOS 10.15+ (Catalina) or using the zsh shell:

`emacs -nw` still works, but if you want to make an alias for this (so you don't have to type it in every time) complete the following steps:

1) Navigate to your home directory using `cd ~`

2) Open up the .zshrc file (its okay if it doesn't yet exist) with `emacs -nw .zshrc`

3) Type: `alias emacs='emacs -nw'` (make sure there are no spaces on either side of the equals sign or it will not work)

4) Quit Terminal, restart it, and emacs should now default to the in-Terminal/no-GUI version.